# exception raised during rendering com/android/util/propertiesmap

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: no android previews in the android icon of rendering page]

This is the problem as you can see there is only api 25 to select from preview
what should i select in the sdk manager to solve this issue 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing other packages like Lollipop(Api level 21) should resolve the issue. You can install the packages from sdk manager. Go through [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)